# Query collection where ALL elements of a nested array are not the same value

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregation-framework

I have a data structure of registrations like this:

```
event: "Event A",
level: "A",
field: "Main",
buyer: ["thisuser@gmail.com"],
players: [
  { 
  first: "Bob",
  last: "Baker",
  email: "bobbaker@gmail.com",
  myid: 1234567,
  signed: false
  },
  {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe",
  email: "johndoe@who.com",
  myid: 4325678,
  signed: true
  }
]
```

I'm trying to run a query of players who are registered for events at different levels.   So far I have:

```
db.registrations.aggregate(     
[       
{ $unwind: '$players' },       
{         
  $group: {           
    _id: { myid: '$players.myid' },           
    events: {             
      $push: {               
        event: '$event',               
        level: '$level',               
        field: '$field',               
        buyer: ['$buyer']             
      }           
    }         
  }       
},       
{ $match: { events: { $size: 2 }, 'events.level': 'A' } }     
])
```

I was thinking the last line of the aggregation would work if I was able to compare all events.level to the first record in the events array.  I just don't know how.  I'd like the data to output like so:

```
{ 
"_id" : { "myid" : 1081245 }, 
"events" : [ 
  { "event" : "Women's AA", "level" : "AA", "field" : "PAL", "buyer" : [ "email@osu.edu" ] }, 
  { "event" : "COED A", "level" : "A", "field" : "Main", "buyer" : [ "ngruber@cdeducation.org" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "myid" : 1081202 }, 
"events" : [ 
  { "event" : "Women's BB", "level" : "BB", "field" : "PAL", "buyer" : [ "amothermail@gmail.com" ] }, 
  { "event" : "COED A", "level" : "A", "field" : "Main", "buyer" : [ "emailing@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "myid" : 1081196 }, 
"events" : [ 
  { "event" : "Men's A", "level" : "A", "field" : "PAL", "buyer" : [ "myemail@outlook.com" ] }, 
  { "event" : "COED BB", "level" : "BB", "field" : "Main", "buyer" : [ "hisemail@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "myid" : 1080246 }, 
"events" : [ 
  { "event" : "Men's A", "level" : "A", "field" : "PAL", "buyer" : [ "dude@outlook.com" ] }, 
  { "event" : "COED BB", "level" : "BB", "field" : "Main", "buyer" : [ "fella@gmail.com" ] } ] }
```

I tried changing the last line of the aggregation to something like:

```
{ $match: { events: { $size: 2 }, {$not: {'events.level': '$first'} }} }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: In above sample data first two documents do not contain `event.level` equal to `A` at first position in events array then why would be returned?